# Custom UITableViewCell with UILabel does not update in xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView that loads custom view cells from a xib. In one case, one of the cells has a button that, when pressed, increments the value of a UILabel in the same cell.

In xcode 5, everything works great, the reference outlet in my UITableView class is hooked up to the UILabel, and when the text is set, it shows up.

In xcode 6, the referencing outlet is still set, but it doesn't appear to point at a UILabel that is actually on the screen. When logging the UILabel as the UITableView is set up, several different memory addresses are logged for the outlet from the cellForRow method, which leads me to believe that it's being set up several times and the resulting reference on my outlet is the wrong one. To boot, I can log the value of the UILabel that I have a reference to, and it's value is what I expect, it just isn't shown on the screen.

One solution might be to remake the UITableViewCell in a different way, but I'd really like to know why this is happening.

Edit, some code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ...

    static NSString *drawingCellIdentifier = @"DrawingCell";

    ...


    //drawing options
    else if (indexPath.section == EventDetailsSectionDrawing)
    {
        DrawingDetailTableViewCell *drawingCell = (DrawingDetailTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:drawingCellIdentifier];

        if (drawingCell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *cellOptions = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DrawingDetailTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

            NSDate *rightNow = [NSDate date];

            if ([[TXAccount sharedInstance] isGuest])
            {
                drawingCell = [cellOptions objectAtIndex:EventDrawingDetailXibIndexGuest];
            }
            else if (self.promotion.event.mostRecentDrawing && [[self.promotion.event.mostRecentDrawing.preview_start_date laterDate:rightNow] isEqualToDate:rightNow])
            {
                if (indexPath.row == 0 && self.promotion.total_bids.integerValue > 0)
                {
                    drawingCell = [cellOptions objectAtIndex:EventDrawingDetailXibIndexTokensEntered];
                    NSInteger bidCount = (long)self.promotion.total_bids.integerValue;
                    if (bidCount == 1)
                    {
                        drawingCell.title.text = @"foo";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        drawingCell.title.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bar %li", (long)bidCount];
                    }                    
                }
                else if (self.promotion.event.mostRecentDrawing.winner)
                {
                    drawingCell = [cellOptions objectAtIndex:EventDrawingDetailXibIndexWinner];
                    drawingCell.venueName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.", self.promotion.event.venue.name];
                }
                else if (self.promotion.event.mostRecentDrawing.is_active)
                {
                    drawingCell = [cellOptions objectAtIndex:EventDrawingDetailXibIndexOpen];
                    drawingCell.endDate.text = self.promotion.event.mostRecentDrawing.endDateDisplay;
                }
                else if (self.promotion.event.mostRecentDrawing.startingSoon == YES)
                {
                    drawingCell = [cellOptions objectAtIndex:EventDrawingDetailXibIndexStartingSoon];
                    drawingCell.endDate.text = self.promotion.event.mostRecentDrawing.startDateDisplay;
                }
                else
                {
                    drawingCell = [cellOptions objectAtIndex:EventDrawingDetailXibIndexClosed];
                    drawingCell.endDate.text = self.promotion.event.mostRecentDrawing.endDateDisplay;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                drawingCell = [cellOptions objectAtIndex:EventDrawingDetailXibIndexNoDrawing];
            }
        }

        [drawingCell setupForEvent:self.promotion.event];
        cell = drawingCell;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: You should see several different memory addresses if you have more than one cell on screen; you should see one for every cell. You need to post some code. There really shouldn't be any difference between iOS 5 an 6 in the way a table view works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the views were stored in a single xib and being instantiated was incorrect. I had to move each view into it's own xib, make sure the reuse identifier was set correctly in the xib and make sure that the proper pattern was being used in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
static NSString *activeIdentifier = @"ActiveCell";

...

drawingCell = (DrawingDetailTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:activeIdentifier];

if (!drawingCell)
{
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"DrawingDetailTableViewCellActive" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:activeIdentifier];
    drawingCell = (DrawingDetailTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:activeIdentifier];

}
```